# WPF – Collection ContentProperty

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In the case of a custom **DataTemplateSelector**, I used **ContentProperty** attribute that should represent a collection of **DataTemplates**.

```
[ContentProperty(nameof(Templates))]
public class CustomTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public List<DataTemplate> Templates { get; } = new List<DataTemplate>();

    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        /* … */
    }
}
```

The usage within **XAML**:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MyCollection}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
        <local:CustomTemplateSelector>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:Boolean}">
                <Label>BOOL</Label>
            </DataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type system:String}">
                <Label>STRING</Label>
            </DataTemplate>
        </local:CustomTemplateSelector>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

---

My question is why I can not use the `IList` or `ICollection` data type instead of the `List` data type.

If I use these types, I get a compilation error **Cannot set content property 'Templates' on element 'CustomTemplateSelector'. 'Templates' has incorrect access level or its assembly does not allow access.**

Comment: `public IList Templates { get; } = new List<DataTemplate>();` works.

Comment: @Clemens: Thanks for trying. It does not work for me with target .NET framework 4.6.1/4.7/4.7.1.

Comment: Note that it's `IList`, not `IList<DataTemplate>`.

Comment: That's it – non-generic `IList` works fine. So, I have to use specific implementation like `List<DataTemplate>` or the non-generic one with the risk that developer can include also other types than `DataTemplate`.

Comment: I'm only curious what is the problem with the usage of  `IList<DataTemplate>`.

Comment: Anyway, I can't see a reason not to use `List<T>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`ContentPropertyAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.contentpropertyattribute(v=vs.110).aspx#Remarks) documentation says that

> In order to accept more than a single object element as content, the type of the XAML content property must be supportable as a collection type.

While this is quite vague, it seems that if the `ContentProperty` type is a collection, it must implement the non-generic `IList` interface, which `List<T>` does, but `IList<T>` does not.

So

```
public IList Templates { get; } = new List<DataTemplate>();
```

works, but

```
public IList<DataTemplate> Templates { get; } = new List<DataTemplate>();
```

does not, because `IList<DataTemplate>` is not an `IList`.